# How can I accept integer input while rejecting floats and spaces?

Tags: c++, validation, input, int

I have a menu creation system with a loop to check input. When the input is something like "2.4" or "2 4" it accepts "2" as the first input, then I guess "4" gets stored in the buffer and automatically passes as the next input without waiting.

These two solutions are the closest I could find, but I can't figure out how to implement the first (don't even understand most of what they're using) and the second still accepts non-int numbers.

[Accept only integer to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954714/accept-only-integer-to-input)

[How to make cin take only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-take-only-numbers)

relevant code (sorry, still trying to figure out formatting):

```
int menu(std::vector <std::string> options) //menu creation
{
int input;             //user selection
bool check = false;    //check for valid input
.
.
.
  while(!check)
  {
    std::cin >> input;

    if(std::cin.fail() || input <= 0 || input > static_cast<int>(options.size()))
    {
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore();
      std::cout << wrongInput << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      check = true;       //change flag for valid input
    }
  }
return input;
}
```

I'd like the loop to outright reject anything non-int. I tried having a loop that would check each character sequentially so it would accept multi-digit ints, then fail on a space, "." or character, but it very was clumsy and still didn't work properly.

Comment: read line per line and then use function like strtol to check the conversion occured AND that the whole content was read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read one line, put it into a stringstream and then use `std::nows` to make sure whitespace is not allowed. To make sure that there are no remaining characters after the integer, just check EOF.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::stringstream temp;
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  temp << line;
  int value;
  temp >> std::noskipws >> value;
  if(!temp.fail() && temp.eof()) {
    std::cout << "Parsed a 'pure' int: " << value << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Expected <int>" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

It will allow `123`, `598324` but not `<space>123` or `123.4`

Comment: This works! However, now my loop gets stuck when rejecting invalid input- it claims every entry following is also invalid. I think this still counts as progress- thank you.

Comment: @ZJN I haven't seen your loop, but it should work: https://repl.it/repls/WarlikeBestLinks